# Подскажите, как шифруется или хешируется пароль на сайте VFS global&

Tags: парсер, шифрование, хеширование

Хочу авторизоваться через запрос на сайте. В ответе надо получить access токен.
Сайт https://visa.vfsglobal.com/blr/ru/pol/login

Параметры пост запроса такие:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'lift-api.vfsglobal.com',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,ru-RU;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="116", "Not)A;Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="116"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'cross-site',
    'sec-gpc': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

data = {
    'username': 'wbefuq@mailto.plus',
    'password': 'Qf5TiYh377pkp1B9QNXe7nPhJYGhwNSEUXO864LvoNCn0FPqG4DSj4V8wIetOiOipydyMDYIYooqVLKuhEnWp6s9uofIkjRHF6Cqn/ZkbmwuW9DShOZJDNuYB9jevLLNzs/CiTSiBIQVoEIt+G4jMussOHlJG+kdgcb3TPxZ6BI=',
    'missioncode': 'pol',
    'countrycode': 'blr',
    'captcha_version': 'v2',
    'captcha_api_key': 'fjbrngekngekmkl',
}

response = requests.post('https://lift-api.vfsglobal.com/user/login', headers=headers, data=data)
```

И каждый раз при логине в девтулс в параметрах запроса пароль записан по-разному. Что сайт с ним делает? Подскажите, пожалуйста, как

Для формирования запроса через post в параметр капчи можете любую абрукадабру вводить, сайт не проверяет.
Пароль и логин
wbefuq@mailto.plus
Qwerty12!

Спасибо